# How setLength to RandomAccessFile without write it?

Tags: java, java-io, random-access

I am running the following piece of code:

```
    RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(new File(Download.DESTINATION + Download.getFileName(Download.FILEPATH)), "rwd");
    randomAccessFile.setLength(contentLength);
    randomAccessFile.close();
```

A `contentLength` is about 60Gb. And I expect that this space will be just created on hard drive. This operation should be just byte allocation and cost nothing. I mean that file system just marks that these space is reserved by file. But java writes something to this file:

[image]

Is there a way to disable this? I do not care what file contains right now. All data will be rewritten later. Why java fills this file immediatelly?

P.S. if question is unclear feel free to ask questions in comments.

Comment: What platform? AFAIK not all file systems support something like `fallocate` and it could be that the file has to be zero-initialized.

Comment: Windows 10, ntfs file system on ssd.

Comment: Then the JDK will be using either `SetFileInformationByHandle(..., FileEndOfFileInfo, ...)` or `SetFilePointer()` and `SetEndOfFile()`. Either way the file isn't zero-initialized, and I don't think that the JDK adds any extra initialisation. (NTFS takes care that you only will be able to read null bytes from the preallocated space, but that doesn't require disk writes.) The writes you are seeing are likely the meta data.

Answer (score -2):

randomAccessFile.setLength(1024l * 1024 * 1024 * 60);

Comment: And how does that solve the OPs problem? As far as I understand his `contentLength` contains a value in the order of `1024L * 1024 * 1024 * 60`

Comment: The variable contentLength is probably declared as int and 60GB in bytes exceed the 32 bit size of an int, it will overflow to a negative number.

Comment: I would expect an IOException if the `contentLength` is negative (or the operation to fail silently). Surely I would not expect Java to write wildly to the disk if the contentLength is negative

Comment: `setLength` receives long, which more then 32 bit long.